# Saving primary key in class based view to another view (django)

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I do not know how even find solution for this, but lets start from the begining.

These are my models:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
SPECIES = (
    ("DOG", "DOG"),
    ("CAT", "CAT"),
)
species = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=SPECIES)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
weight = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
color = models.CharField(max_length=10)
isill = models.BooleanField(null=False)
isagressive = models.BooleanField(null=False)
isadopted = models.BooleanField(null=False)
isreturned = models.NullBooleanField()
whichbox = models.CharField(max_length=5)
photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class MedicalHistory(models.Model):
animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
disease = models.CharField(max_length=100)
medicine = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
therapy = models.CharField(max_length=50)
howmuchmed = models.CharField(max_length=50)
daterecord = models.DateField

def __str__(self):
    return self.disease
```

and here are my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', AnimalListView.as_view(template_name='Animals/animals.html'), name='animallist'),
    path('add/', AddAnimal.as_view(), name='addanimal'),
    path('edit/<int:pk>/', EditAnimal.as_view(), name='editanimal'),
    path('detail/<int:pk>/', AnimalDetailView.as_view(template_name='Animals/animaldetail.html'), name='animaldetail'),
    path('medlist/<int:pk>/', MedhistoryListView.as_view(template_name='Animals/medlist.html'), name='medlist'),
]
```

and my views (only two from all)

```
class AnimalDetailView(DetailView):
queryset = Animal.objects.all()

def get_object(self):
    object = super().get_object()
    object.save()
    return object
context_object_name = 'animal_detail'


class MedhistoryListView(ListView):

"PLACE FOR CODE"

context_object_name = 'medical_history_list'
```

In the MedhistoryListView i would like to show a diseases that animal had. There is the link on AnimalDetailView template to the url with Medhistorylistview. My main problem is how to save primary key from one view to another and choose only these objects with specify animal.pk. Like a MedicalHistory.objects.get(animal.pk=pk). Can anyone help me?

Comment: Pass the PK with the URL in the link.

Comment: Why are you saving in your detail view?

Comment: I can see `detail/<int:pk>/`, what pk you are passing in animaldetail ?

Comment: This is primary key for one animal. In this url are every information about one object and pk is primary key for this object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, delete that `get_object()` method in your AnimalDetailView. It is doing nothing other than causing a completely pointless update query.

Now, in your MedhistoryListView, you want to set the queryset to be the set of objects related to the Animal identified by the PK in the URL. So, define the `get_queryset()` method:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return MedicalHistory.objects.filter(animal_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for help. I written get_object() method from documentation because i unterstood it wrong. I thought this is neccesary to pass object to template.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as an indication to future searchers.