# How to use <int:pk> in class-based general views

Tags: python, django

bookinstance_form.html

```
    {% extends "catalog/base_generic.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
path('bookinstance/create/', views.BookInstanceCreate.as_view(), name='bookinstance_create'),
path('bookinstance/<uuid:pk>/update/', views.BookInstanceUpdate.as_view(), name='bookinstance_update'),
path('bookinstance/<uuid:pk>/delete/', views.BookInstanceDelete.as_view(), name='bookinstance_delete'),
```

views.py

```
class BookInstanceCreate(CreateView):
    model = BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'

class BookInstanceUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'

class BookInstanceDelete(DeleteView):
    model = BookInstance
    success_url = reverse_lazy('catalog:books')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms has all course
How to use int:pk in class-based general views, adding bookinstance needs to be associated with Book, so I need to know book.id, but I don't know how to write it in views.BookInstanceCreate.

Comment: Any instance of the model for the form in UpdateView etc. would be present as `instance` in the context (The view will automatically look for it using any keyword arg passed with the key being 'pk' or 'slug'). You can override various methods if any customization is needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving primary key in class based view to another view (django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140368/saving-primary-key-in-class-based-view-to-another-view-django)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question. Every time you fill some model Django automaticly create ID for him. You can call this using int:pk tag. Use classic href
{{ url "bookinstance_update"  BookInstance.id }} and make query of your books  - >
{% for something in BookInstamce%}  i Hope thats what you asked for.